# Retrieve multiple record from database in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to check if **user login only if email exist and activated==1**

set  in database but activated always show null value.

**Image 1:**

[image]

**Image 2:**

[image]

Comment: inside your where clause put `where(array("email"=>$email,"activated"=>1))` and see if it solves

Comment: please put the code in your question as text and not a screenshot of your code

Comment: thanks it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where([
   ['email', '=', $email],
    ['activated', '=', '1'],
])->get();
```

or 
make your where clause with array to check multiple conditions.

You can use Model class to get data using where clause.

[See Queries: Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries)

**Another Example (eloquent):**

```
$matchThese = ['email' => $email, 'activated' => '1'];
//........
//........
$results = User::where($matchThese)->get();
```

Comment: @UNknow mark this question as solved or this answer as correct